# Why does Finder tell me Pixie is zero bytes in size, but takes up 406 KB?

Tags: finder

Pixie, the additional Xcode app for magnifying pixels of the screen and finding their values, takes up 406 KB of space. Finder, however, says that it's zero bytes in size. In the below screenshot, you see that under Size it says "zero bytes", followed by "406 KB on disk". What does this discrepancy mean?

[image: Get Info for Pixie]

I have relaunched Finder, but the problem persists. Pixie is fully functional.

Comment: Interesting...Are you looking at the same Pixie.app from `/Developer/Applications/Graphics Tools`. I just looked at mine from an Xcode 4.2.1 install and it indeed shows the correct sizes.

Comment: @binarybob I have Xcode 4.3.2, and I downloaded the [Graphics Tools for Xcode pack](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-).

Answer (score 1):

I think that this could be the resource fork taking up the space.

See [here](http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/macosx.html) for more details.

Comment: The Contents folder inside the app (revealed with a Show Package Contents) is 353,793 bytes, and its resource fork makes it take up 406 KB. What I want to know is why, while the *contents* of the app take up that space, Finder shows the app itself as taking up 0 B. Other apps seem to display as the size of their contents.

Comment: So much for "the sum of its parts!"